# No space left on device

Tags: debian, webserver, openvz

Hello I'm running openVZ on my debian machine with debian containers and now I can't run apache, because of no space left.

I checked `df -h` for finding which partions is full and here is an output:

```
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   4.8G  356K  4.8G   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                    12G     0   12G   0% /run/shm
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web3/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web4/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web5/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web6/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web8/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web10/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web11/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web12/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web13/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web2/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web14/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web15/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web16/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web17/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web18/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web19/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web21/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web22/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web23/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web25/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web26/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web27/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web28/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web29/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web30/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client1/web31/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client4/web32/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client4/web33/log
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a75ab882-5448-4448-9344-6a93161bc2e5  225G  223G     0 100% /var/www/clients/client4/web34/log
/dev/ploop19310p1                                       4.7G  1.2G  3.3G  27% /var/lib/vz/root/101
devtmpfs                                               1000M     0 1000M   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/dev
tmpfs                                                  1000M     0 1000M   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/dev/shm
tmpfs                                                  1000M  109M  892M  11% /var/lib/vz/root/101/run
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/run/lock
tmpfs                                                  1000M     0 1000M   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                                  1000M     0 1000M   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/tmp
none                                                   1000M     0 1000M   0% /var/lib/vz/root/101/run/shm
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102
devtmpfs                                                 16G     0   16G   0% /var/lib/vz/root/102/dev
tmpfs                                                    16G     0   16G   0% /var/lib/vz/root/102/dev/shm
tmpfs                                                    16G   25M   16G   1% /var/lib/vz/root/102/run
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /var/lib/vz/root/102/run/lock
tmpfs                                                    16G     0   16G   0% /var/lib/vz/root/102/sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                                    16G  868K   16G   1% /var/lib/vz/root/102/tmp
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client4/web37/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web36/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web35/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client4/web34/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client4/web33/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client4/web32/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web31/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web30/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web29/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web28/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web27/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web26/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web25/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web23/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web22/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web21/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web19/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web18/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web17/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web15/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web16/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web14/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web13/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web12/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web11/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web10/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web8/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web6/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web5/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web4/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web3/log
/dev/ploop54675p1                                       221G   94G  118G  45% /var/lib/vz/root/102/var/www/clients/client1/web2/log
none                                                     16G     0   16G   0% /var/lib/vz/root/102/run/shm
```

I don't understand, why `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` disc are full, because there is only one error.log file, which has 0b size...

Can you give me an advice, which disc or partition can be full? Because on virtual machine I have 50% free space...

Comment: Are there any deleted but still open logs? `lsof | fgrep deleted`

Comment: It shows me an long output, mainly:
lsof: no pwd entry for UID ... 
cron      235668               root    5u      REG               0,46         2220   69676093  (deleted)/var/lib/vz/root/102/tmp/tmpfzr8ypz

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to commen coz of my reputation but Michal it seems that you have already figured out the answer through lsof.
Cron is holding a deleted file.
You can either kill cron with the pid as:

```
sudo kill -9 235668
```

else you can just empty the file descriptor as:

```
> /proc/235668/fd/5 " or "> /var/lib/vz/root/102/tmp/tmpfzr8ypz
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to find the largest file and determine if it's useful else rm it. You can change the size of the files below in the command. Also why are the outputs are repeating for the filesystems?

```
find / -xdev -size +100000 -exec ls -l {} \;
```